# Does Outlook prevent unauthorized Windows users from accessing a .PST file?

Tags: windows, security, microsoft-outlook

If one creates a `.PST` file in Microsoft Outlook and does not specify a password during creation does Outlook automatically prevent other users from accessing the data in the `.PST` file? If not, is password-protecting the file the only way to prevent unauthorized access to the contents of the `.PST` file?

Comment: Set the file permissions on the file in such a way only the owner can read/write the file.  Windows respect the file's permissions.  .PST is normally located in a folder only the user can get to, that doesn't stop, a higher permission user from taking ownership of the file though.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can. Just set its "Encrypted" attribute. To do this, close Outlook, open PST file's location, right-click the PST, select "Properties" and click the "Advanced..." button. On the "Advanced Attributes" dialog check "Encrypt contents to secure data" and click the OK, OK.
Now only the user who encrypted this PST will be able to access its contents.

Comment: This only works on the Professional versions of Windows. Also, before one enables Windows Encrypted File System, they ought to understand the need to back up their EFS certificates so they don't accidently lose the ability to access their encrypted files.

Comment: @Twisty: indeed, you have to backup your encryption certificate. BTW, it looks like encryption is available in all editions of Windows 8.1: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8-1/compare/default.aspx

Comment: I believe you're referring to the fact all Win 8 editions support [Device Encryption](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/using-device-encryption). This encrypts an [entire disk](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/10/windows-8-1-includes-seamless-automatic-disk-encryption-if-your-pc-supports-it/) not individual files. EFS works on a file-by-file basis, but requires the Pro eds. of Windows. See [Supported operating systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypting_File_System) and [this article](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/99959-encrypt-decrypt-folder-file.html)

Comment: BTW, I believe the system administrator can disable EFS through group policy (i.e., this works only on the Professional versions of Windows where not disabled by the system administrator).

Comment: Additionally, this [Microsoft TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn645509.aspx) shows that only the Pro and Enterprise editions of Windows 8.1 support BitLocker and EFS (see the section titled *Security and Privacy Technologies by Windows 8.1 Edition*).

Answer (score 1):

For Outlook 2003, the PST file has a format called "Encrypted Compressible".

This is removed as an option from Outlook 2007 and up. For the later versions, you should encrypt using the file system as thims says, or use BitLocker.

Source: [How to encrypt a .pst file for Outlook 2007](http://web.archive.org/save/windowsitpro.com/security/how-encrypt-pst-file-outlook-2007)